# SQLAlchemy: access to existing sequence in reflected database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the existing PostgreSQL database with sequence defined as:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE some_schema.some_sequence_seq
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    START 1;
```

In my python I defined the reflected data_base object as:

```
engine = create_engine(<some URL>)
data_base = automap_base()
data_base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, schema='some_schema')
```

Now I can, for example, access any table in the database using:

```
data_base.classes.some_table_name
```

So, the question is, how can I get nextval value of some_sequence_seq using the data_base object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

```
engine = create_engine(<some URL>)
data_base = automap_base()
data_base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, schema='some_schema')
metadata = MetaData(schema='some_schema')
seq = Sequence('some_sequence_seq', metadata=metadata)
```

Now seq reflects some_sequence_seq and we can use it like:

```
seq.next_value()
```